# Mule CE: rollback when throw exception in one database on serial databases in a Mule flow

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I have the following scenario in a Mule Flow [syncronized]:

1. Pool component [watermark] - Database select
2. Database component - Insert into Database A (Oracle)
3. Database component - Insert into Database B (MySQL)***

In an execution flow, an exception is throws on Database B (***).

How can I rollback in Mule the insert executed in Database A?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting them into Transaction Scope with XA and add error handling for Rollback Exception Strategy?

Look at - [Mule Transaction Management](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/transaction-management)

[Transaction Exception Strategies](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/transaction-management#transaction-exception-strategies)

Comment: I tried and it does not work! I put two database in a Transaction Scope (Mule CE) and the following exception occur: `org.mule.transaction.IllegalTransactionStateException: Only a single resource can be bound to this type of transaction`.  Am I doing somethin wrong? Or, in Mule CE does not possible works with Transaction with more than one database in one scope?

Comment: I changed the title to focus on Mule CE runtime.

Comment: I tested and understand now. Mule 3.7 CE does not have options to select `XA` or `Multi` Transactions. It works just like `Simple Transaction`, by default! Is there another way to implement transactions in Mule CE, like String Framework?

Comment: I didn't see that for CE :). Sorry, I am not aware of any other way at this point.

Comment: Ok! I think that is possible embbed JTA transaction into Mule CE, with hard code, injecting Bitronix or JBoss JTA/XA implementation. But I not found documentation and don't know clearly how to do. If someone knows a way to do this, should be a gread help!